# I'm Having Trouble With a SQL Query in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, linq

I'm trying to come up with a LINQ query that will return the first row with the most hits, followed by the rest of the rows sorted by date desc. Is this possible to do in SQL or would i need 2 separate queries?  My table looks similar to this.

Backend: SQL Server 2008

Table Name: Products

ProductID  ProductName  Hits  DateAdded

1 Coffee  600  5/2/2012
2 Vanilla  800  4/19/2012
3 Chocolate  3000  3/25/2012
4 Oreo  200  2/10/2012
5 Heath  250  5/13/2012
6 Sherbet  550  4/20/2012
7 Mocha  2000  3/22/2012

I would like the results of the query to come back as such: (Chocolate first - based off hits, the rest - order by date descending)

3  Chocolate  3000  3/25/2012
5  Heath  250  5/13/2012
1  Coffee  600  5/2/2012
6  Sherbet  550  4/20/2012
2  Vanilla  800  4/19/2012
7  Mocha  2000  3/22/2012
4  Oreo  200  2/10/2012

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm a LINQ rookie.

Thanks!

Comment: You're going to need two queries; the two selectors are different from each other. In the absence of LINQ, just executing in the database, how would you do this with one query?

Comment: you're basically looking at two different result sets so going to need two different queris

Comment: I always wonder (if the data set is small enough) whether it makes more sense to grab all the data in one round trip to the database and then do the additional sort in memory vs. 2 trips to the database. Nothing I've really tested - just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int maxHits = Products.Max( p => p.Hits );

var query = Products.OrderByDescending( 
                p => p.Hits == maxHits ).ThenByDescending( p => p.DateAdded );
```